# »Ein lange(s) geplantes Auto«

Tags: adverb, adjective-ending

Warum ist hier die Nummer 1 richtig statt der Nummer 2?

> 1) Ein lange geplantes Auto
>
> 2) Ein langes geplantes Auto

Ich interessiere mich nur für Adjektivdeklination.

Comment: Was will dieser Satz aussagen? Bist du Autokonstrukteur und arbeitest lange daran, den Bauplan und den Herstellungsprozess des Autos zu planen? In diesem Fall ist es korrekt von einem geplanten Auto zu sprechen. Oder bist du ein Konsument, der vor hat ein Auto zu kaufen? In diesem Fall planst du aber nicht das Auto, sondern den Kauf: »Ein lange geplanter Autokauf.«

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ist das Auto lang(e) geplant worden (also der Plan der Anschaffung wurde vor langer Zeit getroffen) oder ist das Auto einfach nur lang (Stretch-Limo)?

In *lange geplant* ist *lange* ein Adverb, kein Adjektiv und wird nicht gebeugt.

Comment: Ich meine dass der Plan der Anschaffung vor langer Zeit getroffen wurde.
Kann ich auch schreiben "Ein lang geplantes Auto"? mit lang ohne e?

Comment: *Ein lang geplantes Auto* ist auch richtig, aber uneindeutig. Es kann bedeuten, dass das Auto vom Hersteller als eine besonders lange Ausführung geplant wurde.

Comment: @Janka stimmt, war mir gar nicht aufgefallen. Wobei diese Interpretation wohl hinter derjenigen der langen Planung zurückfällt. *lang geplant* wird ja schon recht oft für *lange geplant* benutzt.

Comment: @orange 14 "Ein lang geplantes Auto" in dem Sinn, wie du es hier vorstellst, ist umgangssprachlich zwar verständlich, jedoch eigentlich kein gutes Deutsch. Geplant ist ja nicht das Auto. Geplant ist die Anschaffung eines Autos. In schriftlichen Äußerungen würdest du also eher schreiben: "Die lange geplante Anschaffung eines Autos". Etwa: "Die lange geplante Anschaffung eines Autos fiel erneut ins Wasser, weil Vater das ganze Geld den Winter über versoffen hatte."

Answer (score 1):

2 ist nicht unbedingt falsch aber ungebräuchlich. 2 kann bedeuten das geplant ist ein langes Auto anzuschaffen. Ein Autovermieter würde sagen: Ich plane ein langes Auto anzuschaffen oder aber Ich habe die Anschaffung einer Stretch Limousine geplant. Man würde eher sagen ein geplantes langes Auto.